# WebStorm not suggesting the icon name in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, webstorm, ionicons

I am trying to find the suggestion in icon names when using the Ionicons in React Native.

If I ask about suggestion, WebStorm shows "No Suggestions" like this.
[image: WebStorm does not show any suggestion for icon name]

But If I mis-type the icon name, WebStorm shows the error that the name is wrong, and shows the possible correct names like this.
[image: WebStorm is aware that entered name is wrong]

This clearly shows that WebStorm knows what should be the value of the name prop, but does not suggest it.

How do I enable this name suggestion in WebStorm?
I am unable to find the option to enable it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this currently, completion for Ionic/React components is not supported. Please follow [WEB-49713](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49713) and linked tickets for updates

Comment: Thanks for the update, hopefully, JetBrains team will add this too in their IDE